# What is the Kotlin way to access members both statically and non-statically in a class hierarchy?

Tags: inheritance, kotlin, static

I have the following design that I want to implement in Kotlin:

A non-trivial size of a class hierarchy, sharing a common root (let's call it `Base`). All classes of this hierarchy have some parameters, which should be accessible both statically (because they are needed in factory methods) and dynamically (because they are needed from outside code). Plus, since I'll be creating a lot of instances of these classes, I'd like to avoid instantiating a list/set of attributes for each instance.

Here is what I've been able to put together, which works, but feels really ugly.

```
abstract class Base {
    open val params: List<Int> get() = Companion.params

    companion object : BaseCompanion()
}
abstract class BaseCompanion {
    open val params: List<Int> = emptyList<Int>()
}

class A: Base() {
    override val params: List<Int> get() = Companion.params

    companion object : BaseCompanion() {
        override val params: List<Int> = listOf(1, 3)
    }
}
```

The part that feels really clunky is that every class that inherits from `Base` has to:

- Have a companion object that inherits from BaseCompanion (it's actually not needed here, but I need something to pass to generic factory methods).
- Include their own static variable params in it.
- Override the params property such that it returns values from its own companion object.

Is there a better, more Kotlin, way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing it the other way around, i.e. pass the list from outside, e.g.:

```
abstract class Base(val params : List<Int>)

class A(params : List<Int>) : Base(params)
```

and on the object creation side just hold that "static" list and pass it to your newly created objects:

```
val staticParams = listOf(1, 3)
val oneOfManyA = A(staticParams)
```

If you still want that look&feel of instantiating the `A` alone without passing the static parameters and/or by holding them in the companion, you can still do so by using the `invoke`-operator:

```
class A(params : List<Int>) : Base(params) {
  companion object {
    private val staticParams = listOf(1, 3)
    operator fun invoke() = A(staticParams)
  }
}
```

now you can just call it as follows and it will instantiate with the static parameters from the companion object:

```
A()
```

Note also: as long as you pass the list as is, all lists share the same contents (as you only pass the reference of the original list)... if you would use something like `staticParams.toList()` you basically create your own new list that will be passed instead, which is disconnected from the original list.

Depending on what you really want to do an extension property might also fit the purpose (that's not a recommendation, just a way to solve the issue ;-)):

```
abstract class Base
class A : Base()


val A.params
      get() = listOf(1, 3)

// or:
val staticParams = listOf(1, 3)
val A.params
      get() = staticParams
```

That way you can spare `companion object`, etc. and have your static list directly attached to `A`. This has its own drawbacks but could be a solution as well...

Comment: I must say, it's an improvement from my original solution, thank you. It looks better. It somewhat feels wrong that the constructor has a parameter that always receives the same value, but since it only gets called from the invoke function in companion object, it may be counted as an internal construct (if you make the the default constructor protected). Cool. I'll still leave the question open if anybody has other ideas.

Comment: @VojtěchČerný it just depends on how you use it... I thought that keeping the constructor visible makes more sense in case you require objects with own lists...  but if it is really that static, making it private may make more sense... if by "leave the question open" you mean: not accepting the answer yet, I am fine with it...  just added another variant using an extension property... maybe you like that more...